# How to solve this error , module not found?

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error , module not found,

Cannot find module 'D:\2022\Full StackProjects\FullStackRegisterLoginPage\server.js'

thank you

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2CWy.png)

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const colors = require("colors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const { errorHandler } = require("../Backend/Middleware/errorHandler");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/api/users", require("./Routes/userRoutes"));

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

userRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  getUser,
} = require("../Controllers/userController");

router.post("/", registerUser);
router.post("/login", loginUser);
router.get("/me", getUser);

module.exports = router;
```

errorHandler.js

```
 const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
 const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 500;

 res.status(statusCode);

 res.json({
   message: err.message,
   stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? null : err.stack,
  });
 next();
};

module.exports = { errorHandler };
```

package.json
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mO4T.png)

check this out , i've upload all code on github
[github repo link](https://github.com/Aditya-Mane007/regsisterLogin)

Comment: Please post your package.json file.

Comment: I've added the image of package.json file

Comment: Please post code, not images of code ...

Comment: What command are you executing to start your server and in which directory are you executing that command? Your `package.json` scripts reference `backend/server.js` yet the path in your error message doesn't mention the `backend` part ...

Comment: The `main` property in your package.json is just set to `server.js` This probably should also be `backend/server.js`. Probably some of the processes involved of starting your server uses the value of `main` to resolve what to run. The `run_main_module` in your stacktrace suggests something like that

Comment: I did try with "backend/server.js" but error is still there

Comment: Your repo is working fine, with both `npm run server` and `npm run start` So if you get an error you are using some other command to start your server, but unless you tell us, what you actually use to start your server nobody can help you

Comment: what actually happening is , i run this command to run server "yarn/npm run server " , all running  good but , as soon as i type some code and save it , in cmd it shows "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..."

Comment: Well, that's expected behaviour of [nodenmon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) because it is *"a tool that helps develop Node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected."* But that has nothing to do with your claimed error of "module not found" ...

Comment: or is there porblem with nodemon?

Comment: thank you for your supports and now error is gone .. , i think problem was the main: " server.js"